# Sending to all users with same Project ID - GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know that a 3rd party GCM server-side application have to provide `Registration IDs` in order to send messages to users.

Is there a way to send messages to all users without have to provide `Registration IDs`?

I know that `Project ID` is not application specific. But can we send messages to all devices registered under the same `Project ID` without providing the `Registration IDs`?

Thanks for the attention. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding there is no way to broadcast a message to all users with a single post.

You need to send every ID in blocks of up to 1000 ID's. So if you have 2200 ID's, you need to split that up into 3 posts. 1-1000, 1001-2000, 2001-2200.

Comment: Same thought. But having the 1000000 users to send us back their Reg IDs and we have to provide 1000000 Reg IDs to GCM server each time we need to send a message is quite inefficient.

Comment: This is how the GCM is designed.. as per I know there no provision of the use case you are trying to support..

Comment: This is correct, you need to send your messages in registration ID batches of 1000. Based on what I remember from the Google IO video I do not think that this will change anytime soon. There are commercial services available that work with GCM to make this easier such as: [AirBop](http://airbop.com/) (which I helped create) and [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) and a few others.